# Unable to find my questions without an accepted answer effectively

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, accepted-answer

I have asked many questions on SO. There are about 30 tabs I have to scroll through to find question for which I have not yet accepted an answer.

Some questions of mine are long-term projects. They may require years to be answered satisfactorily.

In contrast, some questions have shown bugs in Vim and OS X, such that I cannot solve them alone. An example is my question [Unable to have no Scattered windows in Screen by .Xresources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809935/unable-to-have-no-scattered-windows-in-screen-by-xresources)

In short, please **add a feature to SO which allows me see my questions without accepted answers effectively**.

Comment: I second that idea. Shows that this person is not just asking questions to game the reputation system, but wants to actively work with them.

Comment: I started a bounty to make sure that some moderator sees this feature-request.

Comment: He ain't kidding! 376 questions! I went looking for "Scattered window", and gave up!

Comment: Is this still an issue even today? How about using the hidden advanced search? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=

Comment: Cawas is right, it's solved via the advanced search functionality!

Comment: It's really &!$@ing annoying that I have to searching for how to do this, finding this question, and following the suggestion below.  If people are going to be judged by accept rates, and this is advertised anytime one asks a question, then to make finding questions you have yet to answer such a pain in the ass is just ridiculous.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like this idea. I don't see why this shouldn't be a sorting option to go along with the sort options for date, views, and votes.

Answer (score 12):

This functionality is actually already available via the:

`hasaccepted:0 user:me`

search functionality.

[Try it out now!](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A0+user%3Ame)

Comment: This is good, but it needs an `isacceptable` or `hasAnswers` type of filter.

Comment: Yes, the search functionality is there, but there is no button for it.

Answer (score 7):

The full query for questions you asked where you *could* have accepted an answer, but haven't yet:

[`user:me is:question answers:1 closed:no hasaccepted:no`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1+closed%3Ano+hasaccepted%3Ano)

This query yields questions asked by the user, that have 1 or more answers, are not closed, and have no accepted answer.