# Please allow us to browse our own questions by tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, profile-page

It would be really useful to be able to browse my own questions like I can all questions and that is by one or more tags. Sometimes I'm looking for a particular question to reference and just can't find it (without google) but I'll have a fair idea of what it's tagged.

Comment: Similar/dupe(?) of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff perhaps?

Comment: or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1114

Answer (score 5):

This is another request for enhancing the search feature, to wit:

> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:18393+[java]

Also note that the alias

> user:me

is now functional, if you are a logged in user you can search your own stuff by typing "me" instead of your actual id number.

Furthermore the tags listed on the user page now automatically generate this syntax; so when you click on a tag from a user's page you will get just the questions or answers that user has provided within that tag.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed. This is yet another feature request which I think would be excellent to implement along with other useful organization and searching tools on your own library of questions and answers.