# How about a tag-based exploration of a user's profile?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, profile-page

Now the database refactoring is done, would it be possible to explore questions through tags *based on the USER's profile* ?

I.e:

- if I am on a user's profile and I click on one of their Tags 'T', I would like to see the n questions where he/she has put an answer, not the NN questions ever tagged T.
- same goes for the tags beneath a question in somebody's profile
- same for "favorites": click on a tag is a way to filter through all somebody's favorite questions in order to see only the one tagged T

Those requests could be combined with the usual sort directives.

That could mean an API like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/1234/tagged/T or U?filter=tag&sort=votes
http://stackoverflow.com/users/1234/tagged/T or U?filter=question&sort=views
http://stackoverflow.com/users/1234/tagged/T or U?tabs=favorites&sort-top
```

Meaning:

- show me all questions tagged T or U where user 1234 has put at least one answer, sorted by his/her most upvoted answer
- show me all questions asked by user 1234, tagged T or U, sorted by the user's most viewed questions
- show me all favorite questions for user 1234, tagged T or U, from the most recent to the oldest

The first beneficiaries would be the users themselves, for their own profile which can contain a lot of question/answer/favorites.

---

Note:

- this is originally the [UV entry 184781](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/184781-tag-based-exploration-of-a-user-s-profile), which was "under review"
- Other similar ideas on Meta might have already been posted. I just wanted to move this ticket here.
  On the same topic, we have on Meta:

  - [Please allow us to browse our own questions by tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/please-allow-us-to-browse-our-own-questions-by-tag) ([Cletus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/18393/cletus))
  - [Ability to search my stuff?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff) ([dbr](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/745/dbr))
  - [Additional search features/syntax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1114) ([dbr](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/745/dbr))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a fairly dramatic change to the user page, so I strongly suggest anyone interested check it out.

(by that I mean, see what happens when you click on a tag on a user page now.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3a6309%20[clearcase]&tab=newest : nice! Thank you.

Comment: Awww, I was so used to the old way. I would go to my user page and middle click the tags to open the tags I usually go to (I know I should probably be using Interesting Tags for this, but they don't line up in a table and so its harder to quickly open 10-15 of them)