# Search - Advanced Search - Only My Own Questions

Tags: discussion, questions, search, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ability to search my stuff?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff)

Would be nice to see an Advanced Search screen.

And it would be nice to see a checkbox with "Limit Search to my own Questions"

Someone has probably said this already but checkboxes with only search within answered questions and unanswered questions would be handy too.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tentatively going to be done, [according to this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/please-allow-us-to-browse-our-own-questions-by-tag/1356#1356). The syntax would be:

```
[java] --userid:18393
```

To see all answer/questions with a java tag by a particular user.

Answer (score 4):

Or, like [searching-tags], add a delimeter for #searching users#.