# Searching for a tag containing * breaks the site

Tags: bug, status-completed

For whatever reason, I tried to search using a tag containing an asterisk `*` - instead of returning no results, it returns an entirely blank page. For example:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-*
```

It seems that any URL containing an asterisk will return a `400: Bad Request` and an entirely blank page:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
```

The same thing happens if you go to and URL ending in `.config` (as [Brad Gilbert pointed out here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/additional-search-features-syntax/4366#4366)):

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.config
```

Comment: Appears * doesn't work in any type of tag search. Correct if I'm wrong

Comment: Closing since this is not a bug, but a lack of a feature, and because this feature is now requested in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/additional-search-features-syntax and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/please-allow-wildcards-in-tag-searches.

Comment: Well this *is* a bug, there's no reason putting * in a URL should return a blank page!

Comment: OK, I accept that. Reopening.

Comment: :) Thanks. It's interesting that all URL's containing a * break (which makes more sense than only the tags-search, I suppose!)

Comment: Adding an interesting tag like `status-*` does work in the sense that matching questions get the highlight. But it fails in that clicking the button to see all the matches gets the blank page.

Comment: This is exactly what I pointed out in the following url, but you explained much better - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6092/tags-with-in-not-working-correctly-closed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>We now replace the client wildcard (*) with the server wildcard (~) on tags</s>.

*Update:* Due to changes in ASP.Net 4.0 URLs like this are now properly handled:

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-*
```

However, be careful, because the server has rules that the client does not. Most notably, any wildcard searches *MUST* be a minimum of **3 characters** in length (not including the wildcard chars themselves), or they are ignored.

Comment: Thank you!  This was an annoying removal of functionality, but at least it was replaced with a much better version.  Even if it wasn't a "supported" feature before.

Comment: @Nick: then why not display an error page explaining the problem then?

Comment: @Kop - Can you clarify? The recent changes made this more flexible...there should be no additional error pages as a result of the `*` support.

Comment: @Nick, contrary to your notice about the four character minimum, it seems that [`/questions/tagged/php*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php*) seems to work, even though it's only three characters.  Is this intentional, or an oversight?

Comment: @Charles - We relaxed this limit about 8 months ago to 3 characters since that was still reasonable...this post just needed some update love, it's now correct.

Comment: @Nick: I meant, both of these pages should display an error stating that `*` cannot be used without at least 3 letters: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a* and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*

Answer (score 5):

This impacts clicking on interesting tags which use wild-cards. And that *did* work before.

Addition: @Jeff: it certainly did. I could click on *any* of my interesting tags on SO, many of which have wildcards.

Maybe the problem is the creation of the links for clicking on interesting tags, that wildcards are no longer striped out?

Comment: no, it didn't work before.

Comment: I could've sworn that it previously did this, too. Maybe by accident, it stripped out the asterisks and sent you to the C++ tag when clicking on a (asterisk)C++(asterisk) interesting tag

Comment: It worked by taking the asterisk off the tag, so it was displaying something, but not really what you clicked though. Now the link has been changed to include asterisks, its now broken. Took me a while to work it out, but someone pointed it out on a question I asked here on the same subject.

Comment: This now makes having * in my interesting tags very annoying as unless there's a question on the main page there's no other easy way to see questions with that tag

Comment: Something changed recently for sure.  I have almost all wildcard tags that I regularly search by clicking.  I knew it didn't respect the wildcard, but it would strip them out.  Can we get the old behavior back? Or rush the wildcard tag search ability?

Answer (score 0):

This has never been supported, so you're describing a bug in a "feature" that doesn't exist.

Comment: Damn. I was really hoping that it had once worked and i'd just forgotten all about it...

Comment: Indeed, I didn't know if this would work, but it failed in a way I didn't expect (thus the bug-report!) - I've made the question a bit clearer, I hope?

Comment: Well, i want it. So... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/please-allow-wildcards-in-tag-searches

Comment: Shog9: I added it to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/additional-search-features-syntax also

Comment: Ah, cool.        :-)

Comment: Could you just go back to stripping the \* out? My \*sql\* tag would very much appreciate it. He feels so inadequate now that I added a sql tag just to provide a quick link to the questions.

Comment: @Jeff: Could change the behavior from showing a blank page to something more appropriate like a page with an explanation?