# Good Tagging frame - add a new rule

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'm for adding the following rule to *Good Tagging* frame;
**Don't tag with two separate tags (general and specific) when they can be merged into one specific one.**
Example:
not windows and xp but windows-xp
not boost and asio but boost-asio

Comment: What's your rationale here? If i'm filtering on, say, windows questions, i want to get windows-xp questions as well - excluding that tag in favor of one more specific would exclude them from my feed...

Comment: @Shog9 RSS feeds are broken. You should be able to subscribe to multi tags like windows* if you are interested in all windows related questions.

Comment: Ok - so you're proposing a practice that's actively harmful to users of the current SO. That's not good. The wildcard thing has been suggested, you should probably hold off on these recommendations at least until it has been implemented.

Comment: FWIW: the wildcard suggestion is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/please-allow-wildcards-in-tag-searches

Answer (score 3):

As long as it does not get confused with alternate tagging conventions such as using a broad category (such as "sql-server") along with a more specific tag ("sql-server-2005"). This convention allows for people to subscribe to a general tag but still be able to gather enough specificity about the question.

Comment: RSS feeds are by tag, so I want to be following the `sql` tag but not the `sql-server` tag.

Comment: This *alternate tagging convention*, as you call it, is wrong. More general tag is rendundant when there's already specific one.

Comment: No, it isn't.  If following the RSS feed for sql-server also got you questions tagged sql-server-2005, it would be.  But it doesn't, and shouldn't.

Comment: @chaos The problem is RSS feeds are broken because they don't make use of multi tags like sql-server*.

Comment: Okay.  Well, I imagine you should address that first, then.  It doesn't really make sense to change our tagging conventions *as if* that had happened when it hasn't.

Comment: @chaos Okay. I addressed this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4176/make-rss-feeds-capable-of-using-multi-tags

Answer (score 3):

We need to have some method of hierarchical tagging, tagging by inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

There's plenty of tag space to allow a generalisation (which it might actually be if the user isn't familiar with other versions) and some specificity.

I can be quite interested in IIS questions in general on SO/SF and would rather not have to check each specific tag (now that we have IIS4,5,6 and 7).

There's no harm in tagging with a generalisation and a specific version.