# Make RSS feeds capable of using multi tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, feed

We should be able to subscribe to wildcard tags with RSS (like c++*).

Comment: Do you mean multiple tags, or tag wildcards? The first is possible, as Jeff said, the second isn't (as far as I'm aware anyway)

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/please-allow-wildcards-in-tag-searches

Comment: @Shog9 Your suggestion is about searching using multi tags, whereas mine is about rss feeds of multi tags. I guess implementing any of them gives the other one for free but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Piotr: Yes, if you can do a search for it, you can get a feed of the search results with (e.g.) the RSS icon in the address bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now get a feed of wildcards.  At the bottom of a `/questions/tagged/` page (including wildcards) you'll see a RSS link (this isn't new), but the link handles wildcard's much better, for example this page:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b*?sort=newest

Has a feed of:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c%2b%2b*&sort=newest

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can combine tags already.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/bug+status-completed

(note that + has to be encoded if it occurs in a tag)

Comment: Ok. But that's something different.