# Searching on 'interesting tags' sometimes doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed

Hello,

I have the tag "c++*" added as an "interesting tag", so I can see everything tagged by c++, c++0x, c++1x, etc. But when I search for that tag, I get a blank page :(

The URL displays as:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++*

And loads as a blank page:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b*

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We now replace the client wildcard (*) with the server wildcard (~) on tags.

However, be careful, because the server has rules that the client does not. Most notably, any wildcard searches *MUST* be a minimum of **4 characters** in length (not including the wildcard chars themselves), or they are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Try [replacing the asterisk with a tilde (~)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/please-allow-wildcards-in-tag-searches)

Comment: I missed the asterisk :x