# Searching for questions tagged "c#*[~]" only returns questions tagged "c#" not "c#" or "c#2.0" etc

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

The following search:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23~ returns "43,619 questions tagged c#"

Note the single tag in the results despite the wildcard in the search term. However, the following search:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net~ returns "26,058 questions tagged
.net or  .net-3.5 or  .net-2.0 or  .net-1.1 or  .net-4.0 or [lots of other terms beginning with .net]"

This is what I would expect.

Yet I know there are questions tagged [[c#2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%232.0)], [[c#3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%233.0)], [[c#3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%233.5)] and [[c#4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%234.0)].

The same is true if you search for "c++*" (or more accurately "c++~").

<strike>I'm guessing it has something to do with the way # is encoded as %23 and + as %2b.</strike>

Apparently it's [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/please-allow-wildcards-in-tag-searches/1726#1726) - though I'll leave the question open for now in case the 4 character limit can be lifted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcard searches only work when added to a string of **four** or more characters.

---

Just look at the [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/please-allow-wildcards-in-tag-searches/1726#1726) Jeff Atwood posted about this:

> ....
>
> I implemented an experimental
>   "explode" operator which allows you to
>   effectiely do the same thing -- it
>   "explodes" the tags using ~ wildcards
>   in a begins-with and/or ends-with
>   manner.
>
> For example:
>
> all questions tagged bug, but without
>   a tag beginning with "status-"
>   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug%20-status-~
>
> all questions with a tag containing
>   "edit"
>   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/~edit~
>
> I haven't fully tested all the
>   permutations, but **you must include at
>   least 4 characters for it to be a
>   valid match.**
>
> Also: THIS IS EXPERIMENTAL. Like I
>   said!

Comment: I remember seeing that post now - damn, I should have searched more diligently