# Wildcard tag search does not expand to full list of matching tags

Tags: bug, tags, tag-search

If I search for [`arcgis*`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis%7E) on the [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) site, the query returns only the tags:

[arcgis-desktop](/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop)
[arcgis-10.0](/questions/tagged/arcgis-10.0)
[arcgis](/questions/tagged/arcgis)
[arcgis-10.1](/questions/tagged/arcgis-10.1)
[arcgis-server](/questions/tagged/arcgis-server)
[arcgis-javascript-api](/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api)
[arcgis-9.3](/questions/tagged/arcgis-9.3)
[arcgis-10.2](/questions/tagged/arcgis-10.2)
[arcgis-engine](/questions/tagged/arcgis-engine)
[arcgis-flex-api](/questions/tagged/arcgis-flex-api)
[arcgis-online](/questions/tagged/arcgis-online)
[arcgis-silverlight-api](/questions/tagged/arcgis-silverlight-api)
[arcgis-rest-api](/questions/tagged/arcgis-rest-api)
[arcgis-runtime](/questions/tagged/arcgis-runtime)
[arcpy](/questions/tagged/arcpy)
[arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf](/questions/tagged/arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf)
[arcgis-android](/questions/tagged/arcgis-android)
[arcgis-mobile](/questions/tagged/arcgis-mobile)
[arcgis-platform](/questions/tagged/arcgis-platform)
[arcgis-flex-viewer](/questions/tagged/arcgis-flex-viewer)

This looks like a lot, however it is actually not even close to the full [list of tags beginning with "arcgis"](https://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/192765/list-of-tags-starting-with-arcgis):

[arcgis](/questions/tagged/arcgis)
[arcgis.com](/questions/tagged/arcgis.com)
[arcgis10](/questions/tagged/arcgis10)
[arcgis-10.0](/questions/tagged/arcgis-10.0)
[arcgis-10.0-sp2](/questions/tagged/arcgis-10.0-sp2)
[arcgis-10.1](/questions/tagged/arcgis-10.1)
[arcgis-10.2](/questions/tagged/arcgis-10.2)
[arcgis-10.3](/questions/tagged/arcgis-10.3)
[arcgis-9.2](/questions/tagged/arcgis-9.2)
[arcgis-9.3](/questions/tagged/arcgis-9.3)
[arcgis-9.3.1](/questions/tagged/arcgis-9.3.1)
[arcgis-android](/questions/tagged/arcgis-android)
[arcgis-api-wpf](/questions/tagged/arcgis-api-wpf)
[arcgis-collector](/questions/tagged/arcgis-collector)
[arcgis-desktop](/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop)
[arcgis-diagrammer](/questions/tagged/arcgis-diagrammer)
[arcgis-editor-osm](/questions/tagged/arcgis-editor-osm)
[arcgis-engine](/questions/tagged/arcgis-engine)
[arcgis-explorer](/questions/tagged/arcgis-explorer)
[arcgis-flex-api](/questions/tagged/arcgis-flex-api)
[arcgis-flex-viewer](/questions/tagged/arcgis-flex-viewer)
[arcgis-image-server](/questions/tagged/arcgis-image-server)
[arcgis-ios](/questions/tagged/arcgis-ios)
[arcgis-javascript-api](/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api)
[arcgis-license-manager](/questions/tagged/arcgis-license-manager)
[arcgis-local-government](/questions/tagged/arcgis-local-government)
[arcgis-market-place](/questions/tagged/arcgis-market-place)
[arcgis-mobile](/questions/tagged/arcgis-mobile)
[arcgis-online](/questions/tagged/arcgis-online)
[arcgis-platform](/questions/tagged/arcgis-platform)
[arcgis-portal](/questions/tagged/arcgis-portal)
[arcgis-professional](/questions/tagged/arcgis-professional)
[arcgis-publisher](/questions/tagged/arcgis-publisher)
[arcgis-rest-api](/questions/tagged/arcgis-rest-api)
[arcgis-runtime](/questions/tagged/arcgis-runtime)
[arcgis-runtime-sdk-ios](/questions/tagged/arcgis-runtime-sdk-ios)
[arcgis-runtime-sdk-java](/questions/tagged/arcgis-runtime-sdk-java)
[arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf](/questions/tagged/arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf)
[arcgisscripting](/questions/tagged/arcgisscripting)
[arcgis-server](/questions/tagged/arcgis-server)
[arcgis-silverlight-api](/questions/tagged/arcgis-silverlight-api)
[arcgis-silverlight-viewer](/questions/tagged/arcgis-silverlight-viewer)
[arcgis-web-adf](/questions/tagged/arcgis-web-adf)

Is this a known issue, or perhaps working as intended?

Comment: Side question, is there a way to make those tag links point to the GIS.SE site rather than the Meta.SE site?

Comment: I was 95% of the way to writing an almost word for word duplicate of this question when I noticed it in the sidebar.  Let's hope it can be addressed soon.

Comment: I'm assuming that `arcpy` shows up in the list because it has `arcgisscripting` as a synonym.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you try `[arcgis*]` again it will probably return a different selection of tags. Trying that gave me back different tags list then the one presented in question.

Typing `[arc*]` or `[qgis*]` multiple times always gave me back a list of 20 tags.
And when I tried `[arc*] [qgis*]`, this one gave a list of 20 tags starting with "arc" and 20 tags starting with "qgis" back, in total 40 tags for 1 search.

Wildcard tag search is **probably limited to 20 tags** then.