# Wildcard tag search gives only first 3 matching tags to anonymous users

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search, anonymous

When I search `[*dnd*]` on RPG.SE I get nowhere near the correct amount of tags:

[image: search results showing only dnd-5e, dnd-3.5e, and dnd-4e]

Now, I lack an RPG.SE account. When a logged-in user attempted the same search, they said they [got](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58963196#58963196):

> [dnd-5e] or [dnd-3.5e] or [dnd-4e] or [dnd-adventurers-league] or [adnd-2e] or [dnd-3e] or [adnd-1e] or [dnd-beyond] or [dnd-bx] or [odnd] or [dnd-next-playtest] or [dnd-4e-character-builder] or [dnd-becmi] or [dnd-encounters] or [dnd-insider] or [dnd-miniatures-game] or [dnd-holmes-basic]

Which is the tag list I get when I try to *exclude* [`-[*dnd*]`](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5B*dnd*%5D):

[image: search for excluding dnd]

Here's a [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGHc6.gif) to prove that's actually what I searched.

A similar thing happens for attempted searches **while logged-out/anonymous** on Literature (a site where I have an account and thus can test both ways) of

- `[*nson]` vs `-[*nson]`
- `[the*]` vs `-[the*]`

so wildcards on either end can cause a problem. In each case, the first 3 tags in the larger list show up in the search results, but not any others. And all (or at least the first 20) of the tags show up when trying to exclude rather than include.

This is not a duplicate of [Wildcard tag search does not expand to full list of matching tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231364/wildcard-tag-search-does-not-expand-to-full-list-of-matching-tags) because the maximum here appears to be 3, not 20, and logged-in-ness matters

<sub>To be clear - this is about incomplete searches *when tags exist*. When they don't it breaks in a different way... but that's a different bug report</sub>

Comment: Dupe-closing myself because of the line "Anonymous users are limited to... three tags at a time" - not something I was looking at originally because I assumed wildcards were borked somehow, not more fundamental limits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is working as intended. The wildcard search *does* expand to all tags, but anonymous users are limited to searching using only three tags at a time. So it chops off all the other tags because they exceed the anonymous-user limit.

The same thing would happen if you manually typed in more than three tags at a time in an anonymous search - it would only keep the first three. We require being logged in to do more advanced/complex searches.

Comment: Makes sense! It was just rather confusing to have different numbers of tags show up for the include/exclude search.

Comment: what about when negating, or the use case on the literature stack?

Comment: I don't have a strong opinion on it working for excludes differently. It doesn't cost any additional resources to exclude more things, but it does cost more resources to include more things (that's not *strictly* true, but in general).

Comment: @Pureferret the reports for Lit were for me being logged out at the time - I wanted to be able to cross-check logged-in and logged-out states

Comment: If it's not too complex, maybe the check can be changed to "logged in anywhere in the network"?