# Tag formatting doesn't work if tag contains *wildcard characters; ie: [tag:git*]

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering, wildcards

Formatting tags with `[tag:]` does not work if the tag contains [wildcard characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/please-allow-wildcards-in-tag-searches).

For example:

- `[tag:git]` → [git](/questions/tagged/git)
- `[tag:git*]` → [tag:git*]