# Tag wildcards `*` break URL parsing in chat

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks, wildcards

URLs containing [tag wildcard characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/please-allow-wildcards-in-tag-searches) `*` do not work properly in chat.

This means that a chat message containing the URL [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java*) will redirect to [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) when clicked.

As a workaround, it is possible to manually hyperlink URLs with asterisk characters using markdown formatting. (i.e. `[java*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java*)` = [java*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java*))

You can see this for yourself in the [Stack Overflow Chat Sandbox](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/38169849#38169849).