# Tags with * in not working correctly?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, wildcards

I have some interesting tags stored on Stack Overflow with * in them (e.g. [c#*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23*) or [delphi*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi*)) and they no longer seem to be working. I'm fairly sure they did since I remember setting them up after reading [this blog post about when they were introduced](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/). I just get a completely blank page when clicking on them.

I've also tested storing interesting tags on the other sites with * in and they all seem to be affected. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work concerning the highlighting of the tags. It does not when clicking on it to see all questions with corresponding tags. It used to show you only questions with the tag stripped from the * wildcards, so for *slq* that was sql. It sometimes still does right after adding the tag to the list.

You get some more information in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3898/did-the-wildcard-tag-feature-get-removed) duplicate.

**Edit** This feature has been extended and fixed. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16852/cant-set-up-interesting-tags-using-to-allow-wildcard-searches/16857#16857) for a snapshot of the time being.

Comment: Thanks for the further info, but I'm fairly sure clicking on a tag of say delphi* did actually work previously. Now I get a blank page, surely that can't be right?

Comment: As I said, it used to give you everithing tagged with [delphi] when you clicked on [delphi*]. The blank page now is a bug, clearly. Just explaining what happens.

Answer (score 1):

We now replace the client wildcard (*) with the server wildcard (~) on tags.

However, be careful, because the server has rules that the client does not. Most notably, any wildcard searches *MUST* be a minimum of **4 characters** in length (not including the wildcard chars themselves), or they are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting tags feature only highlights questions that have tags that match your pattern.

However, you can't click on the tag with a wildcard in it and have it filter questions like you would with a tag without a wildcard.