# Linking interesting tags that include wild card

Tags: bug, tags, hyperlinks

> **Exact Duplicate:**
>   [Clicking on tags with wildcards gives you a blank page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6441/clicking-on-tags-with-wildcards-gives-you-a-blank-page)

I think since yesterday links in the interesting and ignored tags sections that include wildcards changed their behaviour to the following:

<kbd>python*</kbd> -> `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python*`

That page obviously doesn't exist and I'm getting a blank page. Wouldn't the original behaviour that linked to: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python` be more useful?

**Edit**: after reading [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6092/tags-with-in-not-working-correctly/6100#6100) and following re-adding advice, I can confirm that re-adding works *until page is reloaded*. So it clearly is a bug.

**Edit2**: this is **not** a duplicate of [Searching for a tag containing * breaks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1649/searching-for-a-tag-containing-breaks). I'm not searching for anything. These are links in interesting/ignored tags sections! And the change has happened sometimes yesterday. The previous questions have to do with completely different issues. Please open this question.

**Edit3**: this is not a *duplicate many times over*. The

<kbd>python*</kbd> linked to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python`

now it links to: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python*`

How is it a duplicate?

here is the except form  [Kyle's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3898/did-the-wildcard-tag-feature-get-removed/3900#3900):

> When you click on a wildcard tag, it does not (and never has) taken you to **a list of questions with tags that match that wildcard**.

(highlighting mine). Yes, Kyle, it never has taken you to a list of question that match that wildcard. But it has taken you to the one single tag (`python` in this case). What is it if not a regression in usability is beyond me.

Comment: I expanded the duplicate section to include 4 links. Did you review them? I'm pretty sure you'll find your exact problem in more than one of them.

Comment: question that were closed as duplicates but aren't.

Comment: I do accept that slightly different triggers have caused the same error, so I've opened back up http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6441/clicking-on-tags-with-wildcards-gives-you-a-blank-page which really is an exact duplicate of this question

Comment: thanks for that. I'd appreciate if that question were tagged properly.