# Allow wildcards in ignored/interesting tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-watching, ignored-tags, wildcards

I'd like to be able to specify an interesting or ignored tag via a wildcard.  May tags which cover similar topics have common roots.  For example

```
windows
windows7
windows-vista
windows-xp
windows-errors
windows-xp-sp3
```

would all match the wildcard `windows*`.  Someone who finds one of these tags "interesting" would probably find all of them to be "interesting" (or vice versa, if they want to ignore all the windows related stuff, they would need to ignore all of these tags).

I realize that technically everything tagged `windows-xp` should also be tagged `windows`, but that's not the case.  (https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp)

Comment: +1 because I was just wondering if I could do '*'duplicate'*' on my ignore list...awesome!!!

Answer (score 11):

We now replace the client wildcard (*) with the server wildcard (~) on tags.

However, be careful, because the server has rules that the client does not. Most notably, any wildcard searches *MUST* be a minimum of **4 characters** in length (not including the wildcard chars themselves), or they are ignored.

Comment: No love for `php*`?

Comment: s/love/hate/ Or ios*?

Comment: Is the limitation of a minimum of 4 characters in length still there? I think I can favorite `php*`.

Comment: @hims056 [it is unclear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270315/364344) whether the 4 characters is (still) correct. There used to be a message that said so, but the behavior said (and says) otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

You can already do this.

Comment: I feel like a tool for not knowing this! Just optimized my interesting tags.

Comment: Note the issues that malach links to in his answer though.

Comment: omg I was just going to ask for the same feature!

Answer (score 2):

There have been quite a few questions concerning this. You can use * as a wildcard as seen here in the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards). It has its limitations, as it only marks or hides the questions in the list and does not allow you to click on the tag and get a combined list of all tags matching thee wildcard, as discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6092/tags-with-in-not-working-correctly-closed) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/linking-interesting-tags-that-include-wild-card-closed) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6441/clicking-on-tags-with-wildcards-gives-you-a-blank-page).

Comment: The closest is to replace '`*`' with '`~`', but that is still an experimental feature.

Answer (score 1):

As ChrisF says, you can already do this: ["Interesting and Ignored Tags Now Support Wildcards"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/)

> Simply specify one or more asterisks to match any number of characters, either in the middle, the beginning, or the end of a tag. So all these should work as you might expect:
>
> ```
> *.net*
> jquery*
> *c++
> ```