# When should product versions be included in tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

1. If a question has been tagged with <kbd>sqlserver-2008</kbd>, should it also be tagged with <kbd>sqlserver</kbd>?
2. If a question has been tagged with <kbd>sqlserver</kbd> and references a feature only present in SQL Server 2008, should it also be tagged with <kbd>sqlserver-2008</kbd>?

Comment: How about choosing between sql-server and sqlserver and SQLServer and SqlServer and SQL-server and all other spellings? It would be easier if all tags were converted to lower-case, with dashes replaced by spaces. Right?

Comment: @Workshop Alex: I'm really focussing in on whether versions should be included in tags for this question, although you may have a point.

Comment: @Workshotp Alex, I like your thinking but I would replace spaces with dashes ;o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally if I have an SQL Sever question, I will only tag it with the specific year if it is an absolute requirement and generally I will include both "sql-server" and "sql-server-[year]".

It is also possible that users can set up an interesting tag for "sql-server~" that will allow for them to see any tag that starts with "sql-server".

Comment: You can't set up tags like "sql-server~". The system allows you to enter it and displays it correctly initially. Selecting it gives the desired results, but when you return to the main page the "~" has been stripped off.

Comment: I just tried this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server and got back 7,500 records. 

Then I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server~ and got 9,399 records (the tilda wasn't stripped off.

Answer (score 5):

Like many other users, I watch lots of different tags; sqlserver, sql-server, ms-sql, etc. This isn't a good solution, but is a result of letting users create their own tags, and isn't really that much overhead.

On the other hand, when asking questions, I'd stick to one tag rather than using multiple (redundant) tags: sqlserver if the question is common to many versions, or sqlserver-2008 if it references some feature specific to that version.

This saves polluting the tag-space, frees up some tags for moderators and future editors, and avoids annoying people who have no interest in SQL Server 2005 if that's what my question relates to :)

Answer (score 0):

I would tag it sql-server for sure. This is on my favourite tag list. sql-server-2008 is not on that list. I do not want to put every version there.
I think you can omit versions in tags completely and point this out in your question only.

Answer (score 0):

Until we had the search functionality using ~ as a wildcard (server side * that is, such that [sql-server~] finds all tags including the year, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/allow-wildcards-in-ignored-interesting-tags/16615#16615)), I would have voted to use both the generic and the specific tag.

But now, I can use [sql-server*] on my preferred tags and [sql-server~] when searching for questions I would like to offer answers to. So I now adopt using the generic tag unless the question is version specific.

Answer (score 0):

I was originally going to post that I liked having multiple tags such as sql-server and sql-server-2008 because I then have the flexibility to search all sql server questions OR sql server 2008 questions.

Then I discovered that you could put a "~" in the URL for a wild card and I changed my mind.  Now I think you should just put in the sql-server-2008 and let me put in the "~" on my own.

Just my 2 cents :)