# Ignore tags using wild card

Tags: support, tags

**EDIT/EDIT**

Ok, my question is: Can I ignore all the tags but my favorites?

If so, please tell me how with a very small example ( take javascript tag for instance )

If is not possible just tell me so. I'm fine with that.

**Original question**

How can I ignore all the tags but those that I've marked as my favorites? Should I came up with an special reg-exp or something?

Currently may tags are: java, c#, javascript, ruby, python

How can I have the rest ignored?

If I just add "*" this is what I've got:

[alt text http://img264.imageshack.us/img264/8575/capturadepantalla200912b.png](http://img264.imageshack.us/img264/8575/capturadepantalla200912b.png)

Not very useful btw.

Comment: This is a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/allow-wildcards-in-ignored-interesting-tags

Comment: AEther: I saw that question already, but can't just figure out how to ignore everything but my favorite tags. But that's probably me, if you tell me how to do it ( or that It can't be done ) I will appreciate it. ( and mark you as accepted of course )

Answer (score 7):

You can use * wildcards in the interesting/ignored. Since that's performed on the client there are no limitations.

On the server, the * is converted to ~ (ASP.NET url limitations) and wildcards must be a minimum of 4 characters in length. Well 5 characters including the wildcard.

Comment: But,but but.. .would that mean that I have to add many entries? I mean, should I add `a*,  c*, d*, e*` ? and so on?  I guess my real question is "How to use wildcards" in tags ignoring?

Comment: uh.. just add a tag with one character "*"? I think we're overthinking this :) (caveat: only works on the client. We support crashing your own machine at will!)

Comment: Well, yeah , but that pretty much hides my favorites also and leaves me with a very very odd SO page, completely empty.  Mmmhhh ... I have this feeling that I'm missing something really really trivial here.

Comment: The problem is that ignored tags override favorites, which is a reasonable way to operate only if you are interested in a majority of the questions on SO.  This position seems less likely to be the case for most people as time goes on.  It's particularly hard on those with narrow interests to find questions which are interesting to them.  A tag hierarchy would help as well.

Answer (score 2):

Greasemonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Hide Non-Interesting
// @namespace      http://www.stackoverflow.com/
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

$('.question-summary').filter(':not(.tagged-interesting)').hide();
```

Comment: I guess this is a good chance to ask: What am I suppose to do with that? Do I put that on a file and ... then what? What is Greasemonkey?

Comment: Explain it to as if I didn't knew what are you talking about.

Comment: Greasemonkey is a firefox extension that lets you run custom javascript when browsing certain web pages.  There are also ways to use the same scripts for IE and Opera.  The script itself is a jQuery one-liner that will do as you asked, hiding all questions which are not in your interesting tags.

Comment: The weblog about Greasemonkey: http://www.greasespot.net/