# Allow batch adding or removing tags from interesting/ignore lists

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-watching, ignored-tags, tags

I want to be able to bulk add or remove tags from my watched lists of interesting and ignore using wildcards.

So if I entered **[php*]** into the tag field it would then either add or remove all 
tags that match the seed wildcard (i.e.: **[php]**, **[php4]**, **[php5]**, **[php-framework]**, etc.).

Comment: Here's one duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/allow-wildcards-in-ignored-interesting-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, you can already use wildcards.

Entering "php*" without the quotes will highlight anything matching [php], [php4], [php5], etc.

Comment: entering "php*" without quotes adds them, but how about removing them? what's the syntax?

Comment: @1ch1g0 it doesn't add those tags separately.  It adds one `php*` "special" tag.  You remove this the same way you remove any other tag.

Comment: @Joel, what i mean is, say i already have tags `php4, php5, phpbb` for example. how to remove in one go ? right now, i have to click on the cross (remove icon) ON EACH tag everytime i want to remove tags.

Comment: @1ch1g0 - is that really such a burden?