# Please add wildcard support to the StackExchange™ GlobalTag MegaBlender™

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

> This is an intentional re-post of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68328/cross-site-tag-sets-are-live-feedback/68330#68330) because [waffles said so](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/260826#260826).

The existing boxes for adding "interesting" and "ignored" tags supports wildcards. For example, entering "*friday*" will highlight all of `[always-friday-in-iceland]`, `[always-hydrogen-on-friday]`, `[thank-fsm-its-friday]` &c. as "interesting" (or "ignored").

Can we get similar support on this StackExchange™ GlobalTag MegaBlender™ thing?

Refs for the wildcard syntax: [relevant MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/allow-wildcards-in-ignored-interesting-tags), [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/)

Comment: Congrats on becoming Community Manager! By the way, what exactly is that GlobalTag MegaBlender™? Could not figure if you mean the tag editor or the top right search box? :)

Comment: Thanks! And sorry, the post where that term was introduced has since been deleted, and it never really caught on. It's the list of tags that applies to all sites (i.e. network-wide) on stackexchange.com.

Comment: Oh, you mean [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SrXVK.png)? Almost forgot about it, maybe if they add "Tags" page to http://stackexchange.com where it will also be located such a term will catch up better. Now as employee you can push them towards such a page! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done!  A blog announcement is coming soon, but you can add wildcards of the form `*tag*`

Comment: Could this be used to aggregate all questions from a site?  Probably wouldn't be the most efficient, should this be a separate feature request?

Comment: @rchern Open a new feature request.  Wildcards have a minimum of 3 characters, so you'd have to do every combination `*aaa*`, `*aab*`, `*aac*`...which probably wouldn't be very efficient :)

Comment: Done:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69237/please-allow-including-a-full-site-in-the-stackexchange-globaltag-megablender-a