# Please allow including a full site in the StackExchange™ GlobalTag MegaBlender™ aggregation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

[Wildcard support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69230/please-add-wildcard-support-to-the-stackexchange-globaltag-megablender) is a great step, however I'd like to propose going a step further.  For smaller sites, it isn't as necessary to limit things by tags because you aren't getting overrun by the immense traffic like on SO.  For StackExchange.com to truly be a place for aggregation, instead of just one more place to look at, it'd be great to be able to say *show me everything from WebApps plus [sushi] on cooking plus [c#] on SO* for instance.

Comment: I vote for this as well, especially when you consider that on young sites like Cooking, most members tend to really suck at tagging things correctly.

Comment: @Popular, see the comment on the question I linked to (your question).

Comment: ah, yes, also that.

Comment: I had the same thoughts on my comment on the blog post http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/#comment-51695 I want to see the Android.SE plus the Android tag across all sites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done.  Just click the **add entire site** link at the top of the "Add Tags" section to toggle into adding a site mode.

Also, as a counterpoint to Jeff's argument, I believe that this does fit in well with the philosophy of the feature, which is **show me all the stuff I'm interested in across a bunch of sites**.  Jeff's right that if you want to see every question, the right place to go is still that site, but maybe I want to aggregate several smaller sites and watch all of their new questions in one place.  Now I can :)

Comment: Exactly!  Using Jeff's example "for the sites you don't live in, but you might like to visit there once in a while*:  this would describe cooking for me for example, but there isn't a set of tags on cooking I'd want to limit things too.

Comment: I think "smaller sites" is the key, as it takes a long time for a usefull set of tags to be created on new sites.

Comment: I'll get you Fullerton! And Emmett too!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this fits well with the philosophy of the feature. It's about questions with specific tags, not all questions.

If you want to see *every* question on a site -- *go to that site!*

Tag sets are really for the sites you don't live in, but you might like to visit there once in a while.