# Could we have the number of questions displayed for a given tag-set?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tag-filters

The new "[Tag-Sets on StagExchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/)" feature is awesome!
Combined with the "[StackExchange™ GlobalTag MegaBlender™ wildcard support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69230/please-add-wildcard-support-to-the-stackexchange-globaltag-megablender)", browsing specific tags on multiple StackExchange site has never been easier.

Except for one little tiny detail:

When I was browsing those same tags on *one* site (like SO), I always had the **number of question displayed prominently** on each page:

[image]

**That helped to quickly see if any new questions popped-up since the last refresh.**

But with a tag-set in StackExchange, I have to:

- memorize the current question
- refresh
- look for said question further down the page to see how many new questions were asked since the last visit.

That "total number of question" was convenient to quickly achieve the same result.

Is there a possibility for the dev team to add it (prominently) on each tag-set pages when they are browsed (by activity, creation or unanswered order)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I did notice this morning the numbers between parentheses indicating the new questions since the last visit.
(revision: 2010.11.9.4)

[image]

Certainly a step in the right direction.

Even better would be some visual clue around the questions themselves indicating they are new: right now I have to count the seven firsts to make sure I have them all covered.
When there are only two new questions, it is easy, when there are more than 5 or 10, it is more cumbersome.

But anyway, nice feature. Thank you.

Comment: The question link color is different for new vs old, but perhaps it's a bit too subtle?

Comment: Marking this as [status-declined], because we decided to go a different route as you discovered (showing # of questions with activity since you last checked)

Comment: @David: I find your "new route" perfect! I am very happy with it :) Again, thank you.

Comment: @David: about the color, I confirm it is not enough. Only border style can be seen whatever the color display quality is on the end-user screen. No border = no guarantee your subtle color nuances will actually show up.

Comment: @VonC we now highlight unread questions.  This should be much easier to see.

Comment: @David: much better indeed. I am conflicted about the new homepage changes (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/). With all your work on tag sets, it looks more and more like I will never see any StackExchange homepage anytime soon ;)

Comment: @David: I don't see the (x) new questions number anymore in any of my tag sets. I suppose this was too taxing on the database?

Comment: @David: never mind. I see them at work, which should mean I must have been disconnected (logoff) from stackexchange at home this morning.

Comment: @VonC yes, you should always see them when logged in (if there are any)

Comment: @David: I see (and it works now that I am logged, so it's perfect). Any chance of seeing featured question one day? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70967/is-it-possible-to-add-the-featured-questions-category-for-the-tag-sets