# Is it possible to add the "featured questions" category for the tag sets?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, tag-filters, featured-tag

When you define a tag set in the StackExchange site (see blog post "[Tag Sets on Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/)"), you currently have the corresponding questions displayed by:

- activity
- newest
- no answers

Would it be possible to add the "featured" category in order to see, for a tag set (even across multiple sites), all featured questions?

[image]