# criteria on sort-order for tag sets are no longer working: "Oops! Something Bad Happened! "

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-filters, sorting

A simple tag set like "java" works just fine

https://stackexchange.com/tagsets/224/java

The same tag set ordered by "newest", "activity" or "no answer" **won't work if logged in**:

https://stackexchange.com/tagsets/224/java?sort=creation

It will display the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page if logged in (and will work if not logged in)

It was working yesterday, but not this morning.
Is there any recent modification on how those tag sets are displayed?

Comment: Same error here.

Comment: yes, definitely reprodicible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that.  The bug was actually with *switching* the sort order.  Because of some other changes that went out yesterday, it was crashing when trying to save your sort order preference.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: no problem. It works :) Thank you. Just on the principle, is adding "featured" sort order possible? (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70967/is-it-possible-to-add-the-featured-questions-category-for-the-tag-sets )

Comment: @VonC It's possible, but it wouldn't be trivial.  If enough people vote for that feature request we'll consider it.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I wouldn't hold my breath about a massive upvote for that feature request though. I have the feeling the number of users actually using tag set is not very high ;)