# All filter-tags stopped working 11 hours ago on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-filters, tags

This is a bit similar to "[criteria on sort-order for tag sets are no longer working: "Oops! Something Bad Happened! "](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72298/criteria-on-sort-order-for-tag-sets-are-no-longer-working-oops-something-bad-h)", except this isn't limited to one criteria:

Even a simple filter-tags like java: https://stackexchange.com/tagsets/224/java doesn't display any new questions since 11 hours ago.

Any idea why?

Comment: Same thing happening here.  Can't get any of my filters to show anything new any more.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok. At least it is not just me ;) Tested on different computer/browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A (technically impossible)* `null` snuck into the service responsible for aggregating data across all the sites in the Stack Exchange network.  It's been cleaned up, and after churning through a few hundred thousand backlogged events we're back in business.

<sub>*Spot the operative word.  We're checking for the impossible now.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working just fine now.

Comment: SE: solving impossible problems with unbelievable solutions!