# Low volume tags of high priority to SO user

Tags: feature-request, tags

The new tag-based questions pages are useful.

However, I try to pay attention to a specific low-volume tag (~300 posts total), and would like to be sure of seeing those questions whenever they show up.  Despite being on SO for far too much time this week, I managed to miss a few of the incoming questions in the tag of special interest.

Is there a way to ensure that selected important tags make it through the filtering despite being low volume (and therefore not of importance to most SO denizens)?  Is it something that SO can do automatically?

Clearly, the fallback is what I use anyway - check the tag explicitly.  And I'm annoyed with myself for not doing so...but I wonder if there is any call for some sort of 'More Important To Me Than Just Interesting' tag classification.

Comment: Ditch the SO homepage and go for SE tag-sets: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/ (as I say in http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/#comment-51797) It really got quite good as illustrated in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69408/could-we-have-the-number-of-questions-displayed-for-a-given-tag-set