# Make 'Ignored Tags' a little more encompassing

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

For example when I block [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat), I'd also like to have [tomcat6](/questions/tagged/tomcat6) [tomcat7](/questions/tagged/tomcat7)     [tomcat5.5](/questions/tagged/tomcat5.5) also blocked. This is one example, but it occurs often like in case of [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio).

The current interface makes it a little tedious to block entire family of tags and one may not even know all the that tags exists in a given family. Ignored Tags is really a nice feature, however, it will add to utility if it can be made more encompassing.

Approaches I can think of:

- **Wildcards**: Thus tomcat* blocks all of the tags starting with tomcat
- **Technology Stack**: In this approach, entire technology stacks can be blocked thus for example, .NET blocking will block stuff like [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)[asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)[.net](/questions/tagged/.net) and others, but this would require classification of tags into tech-stacks.
- **Eco-System Level Blocking**: Block entire eco-system around the tag being blocked, for example, a block on java will block every single thing related to java including tags like spring, hibernate, jsf that are explicitly and only related to java. Again this would entail delineating relationship between tags. In fact this can result in (pseudo)domain specific site for its users; if someone is only concerned about javascript, he can block all other 'eco-systems' and the site would feel as if it were dedicated to javascript.

(Better yet, 'Eco-system' level whitelist, wherein you add the eco-system which interests you, rest all are blocked by default.)

Comment: `tomcat*` already works: [Allow wildcards in ignored/interesting tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/allow-wildcards-in-ignored-interesting-tags)

Comment: Checked, that works. Never knew it.

Comment: @Kobi That should be an answer ;)