# C# wildcard tag in Favourite Tags list

Tags: bug, tags, tag-watching

If I add [`*.net*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*.net*) to my *Favorite Tags* list I can see all questions with a tag that contains the substring `.net` (as well as a summary list of tags matching `*.net*`)

If I add [`*C#*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*c%23*) I am only shown the `C#` tag, no other matching tags such as `C#-4.0`, `C#-5.0` are displayed in the page or matching tag summary.

[`*C#-*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*c%23-*) works as expected, but of course omits `C#`.

Is there a way to get `*C#*` to behave as expected?

**Edit**

`*ba*` shows nothing and displays the error:

> Wildcards must have at least 4 characters, otherwise they will be ignored.

So presumably the character count for `C#` is applied to `C%23` ?

Comment: Wait, you can use *wildcards* in your tag list?! How cool!

Comment: `facebook-c#-sdk` isn't shown either?

Comment: If I remember correctly animuson said that wildcards on tags only works with a 3 letter string.