# Wildcard tags can no longer be watched or ignored

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, ignored-tags, tag-watching

While editing my watched tags list on [RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com), I received an unexpected error message saying that "gm does not exist on this site".

The reason why the error was so surprising was that I never had `gm` on my watched tags list in the first place (and no, I wasn't trying to add it, either).  What I did, however, have among my watched tags was the [wildcard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/allow-wildcards-in-ignored-interesting-tags) `gm-*`, which would match any of the [several tags on the site beginning with "gm-"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gm-*).  However, now (after adding a completely unrelated tag to the list) it was gone, and trying to add it back just yielded the same error message.

A little more testing revealed that this issue affects all SE sites, and that it does not actually depend on whether the "base" tag exists; rather, the SE software simply strips away the wildcard (and the hyphen) from all tags when editing the watched tags list.

For example, trying to add `java*` to my watched tags on SO (because I like [both Java and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java*), of course) just resulted in `java` being added instead.  Also, trying to add `*script` (because I also [really like all scripting languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*script)) just yields the error "script does not exist on this site".  And trying to [narrow it down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/j*script) to just `j*script` yields the even stranger error "j script does not exist on this site" (yes, with a space in the "nonexistent" tag name!):

[image: Screenshot]

Anyway, [watching or ignoring wildcard tags used to work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/allow-wildcards-in-ignored-interesting-tags), so this is a regression, and I haven't been able to find any statement that it would be intentional.

I suspect this regression occurred as a side effect of [the changes to favorite tags a few months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching), but none of the answers in that thread mention it, and it's been long enough since that announcement that it's better to report this as a separate bug.

Of course, as a work-around, I can just manually expand the wildcard and add all the matching tags to the list.  But in some cases (e.g. language tags with lots of version-specific variants, [like, say, `c#-*.*` on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-*.*)) this can get pretty awkward, especially since the automatic dropdown shows only a limited number of matches.

Ps. An easy way to reproduce this bug is to try to watch (or ignore) the wildcard tag `status-*` here on meta.  Currently, all you get is an error messages saying that "status does not exist on this site".

Comment: Hmm, definitely not intentional. I made a change to that widget to support tag synonyms, so this is very likely my fault. My intent was to preserve wildcard support, so I'll be taking a look at that first thing tomorrow. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad - I switched the Watch/Ignore code to use a different tag input sanitization method that supported synonyms and *claimed* that it supported wildcards, but in fact did not. :)

That's fixed now, so you should be able to use wildcards in watched and ignored tags.

Comment: Looks like it's working. Thanks! :)