# Can't set up interesting tags using "~" to allow wildcard searches

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

You can't set up intersting tags like "sql-server~", to get quick searches for wildcarded interesting tags.

The system allows you to enter it and displays it correctly initially. Selecting it gives the desired results, but when you return to the main page either via the browsers back button or by selecting the site logo the "~" has been stripped off.

**UPDATE**

I've just discovered that I don't need to add "mp3~" (for example) as an interesting tag - if you've got a wildcard in your interesting tags clicking on it does the substitution for you so you get the search you want.

I'll leave this question here for now as it does seem to have raised another issue.

Comment: your example is invalid, however, as the server requires a minimum of 4 non-wildcard chars to do the expansion. "mp3" is 3 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rowland: you are right, there just is a small bug in this:

When I enter the (interesting/ignored) tag, in my case delphi*, clicking on it right away will yield only questions tagged [delphi], searching with this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi

Once I return to the main page or refresh the page, it behaves different (as you experienced), and searches for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi~, thus doing exactly what ChrisF is looking for.

Searching for "delphi~" in the search box searches for [delphi] only (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi).

Searching for "[delphi~]" searches for wildcards again (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi~).

Going to the next page resolves the wildtags and lists all tags included:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=delphi%20or%20delphi.net%20or%20delphi-1%20or%20delphi-2006%20or%20delphi2007%20or%20delphi-2007%20or%20delphi-2009%20or%20delphi-2010%20or%20delphi-3%20or%20delphi-5%20or%20delphi-7%20or%20delphi-components%20or%20delphi-library%20or%20delphi-like%20or%20delphi-php%20or%20delphi-prism%20or%20delphi-units%20or&page=5&sort=newest&pagesize=15

I suggest some rework for more consistent results, but I think that one can live with that behaviour. It works fine after the initial add. (Agree with Jeff's comment)

Comment: this won't be fixed -- the initial add happens once, ever, and the page refresh happens every time thereafter.

Comment: Accepting this as it has the explanation in Jeff's comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use "sql-server-*" though...