# Clicking on tags with wildcards gives you a blank page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, hyperlinks, wildcards

> **Related Question:**
>   [Searching for a tag containing * breaks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1649/searching-for-a-tag-containing-breaks)

I have tags in my "Interesting Tags" with wildcards, like `html*`, `php*` and so on. If I click on it it goes to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php*`, and all I get is a blank page. It used to be that clicking on them would take me to the page with questions tagged just `php`. What happened?

Comment: There's an issue with ASP.NET MVC and asterisks in the titles. Nevertheless, this is a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1649/searching-for-a-tag-containing-breaks

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that other one. Sorry. Jeff says in that post that this was never supported, but it used to "degrade gracefully" such that clicking on a tag with wildcards actually took you to the tag page minus any wildcards. It's not behaving that way anymore, which I'd consider a bug.

Comment: I suspect that it may not be (easily) possible to degrade gracefully if the URL contains an asterisk, but it would certainly be possible to make sure that a tag link doesn't contain an asterisk.

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate. I realize they are very closely related, but the other question is complaining about being unable to search for it, I never attempted such a thing. It has always been the case that simply clicking on a tag with wildcards behaved a certain way, and it stopped doing this very recently. This is a bug.

Comment: They're both symptoms of the same problem. It's not whether you *clicked on* a wildcard tag or *searched for* a wildcard tag, it's that you included an asterisk in the URL that causes the blank page.

Comment: Apparently this is a very recent change where clicking on wildcard tags brings up a blank page, so I'll reopen. (hopefully this will be good enough for http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/linking-interesting-tags-that-include-wild-card)

Comment: yes, it's good enough. Could you please tag it properly (or at least copy tags from my question). Apparently, auto suggestions are not that great.

Answer (score 1):

We now replace the client wildcard (*) with the server wildcard (~) on tags.

However, be careful, because the server has rules that the client does not. Most notably, any wildcard searches *MUST* be a minimum of **4 characters** in length (not including the wildcard chars themselves), or they are ignored.

Comment: So that's why `geo*` doesn't bring back all the results for `geospatial` and `geolocation` as well :(