# Can't filter on a tag containing "*"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clicking on tags with wildcards gives you a blank page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6441/clicking-on-tags-with-wildcards-gives-you-a-blank-page)

I use tags like "c#*" in the Interesting Tags boxes to highlight c# based questions - so I don't have to individually tag for c#2.0, c#3.0, c#.net etc, and have similarly used "*vba*" to hide questions related to VBA ( so I can catch tags like excel-vba ).

However, clicking on such tags takes me to a blank page.

Is this a bug, or is the ability to use * to filter tags on the main page "an accidental feature"? Either way, is this something that can be implemented?

Comment: "*" isn't a regexp.  ".*" is a regexp.

Comment: True. Edited to remove regexp from title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/~perl~

It only works if there is at least 4 characters in the string.

---

- [Clicking on tags with wildcards gives you a blank page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6441/clicking-on-tags-with-wildcards-gives-you-a-blank-page)
- [Searching for a tag containing * breaks the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1649/searching-for-a-tag-containing-breaks)
- [Additional search features/syntax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/additional-search-features-syntax)
- [Please allow wildcards in tag searches](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/please-allow-wildcards-in-tag-searches)

  This is the first [reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/please-allow-wildcards-in-tag-searches/1726#1726) I could find that directly mentions that feature.

  > I implemented an experimental
  >   "explode" operator which allows you to
  >   effectiely do the same thing -- it
  >   "explodes" the tags using ~ wildcards
  >   in a begins-with and/or ends-with
  >   manner.
  >
  > For example:
  >
  > all questions tagged bug, but without
  >   a tag beginning with "status-"
  >   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug%20-status-~
  >
  > all questions with a tag containing
  >   "edit"
  >   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/~edit~
  >
  > I haven't fully tested all the
  >   permutations, but you must include at
  >   least 4 characters for it to be a
  >   valid match.
  >
  > Also: THIS IS EXPERIMENTAL. Like I
  >   said!

  **Jeff Atwood**

Comment: Do you mean "~perl~" will work same as "*perl*" when entered in Interesting Tags box, plus it will work when I click on it ?

Comment: "`~perl~`" works in the url, but I don't think it will work in the Interesting tags box. There is another question that references this, that I have been trying to find.

Comment: Thanks for the links, a quick search didn't turn up these links before I posted this question. I'd thought something like this would have been discussed before .. and I was right. :)