# How to display questions with tag X that are unanswered

Tags: support, tags, unanswered-questions, search, filtering

I can display questions with certain tags and questions that are not answered but not both conditions at the same time? And maybe only questions with no upvoted answers yet. Is this possible?

Which buttons do I have to click to make this work?

Maybe need an advanced search button on stackoverflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Additional search features/syntax?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/additional-search-features-syntax) [Let's go shopping](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10934/search-is-hard-lets-go-shopping)

Answer (score 3):

You do https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/how-to, where how-to is your tag

Comment: can I get this with clicking only or do I have to edit the browser URL each time I need this feature?

Comment: additionally, this doesn't even work. looks at the results the link generates.

Comment: I don't think you can get the link by clicking.  What about the link doesn't work?  One thing that I find annoying, that might be confusing you is that "unanswered" means "no accepted answer".  Intuitively I would think "unanswered" would mean "has no answers/responses"

Answer (score 1):

What? Why isn`t the first answer accepted? Yeah it works all right! Unless you can only accept a *button*. I arrived here because I wanted to ask about the same thing, and this definetively answered my question. Thanks!

Take out "how-to" and instad type in the tag name in the URL given, just like pjb3 said, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/tags gives unanswered questions with the "tags". If you use + and another tag name, it shows unanswered Q`s with both tags. Very convenient!

Although like he also said, what is really shown is Q`s with "no accepted answer".

Answer (score 0):

The proposed method definetively does not work because it shows unanswered questions, but it does not apply the tag specified in the url.

So I hope that stackoverflow will fix this in time.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution in [pjb3's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57637/how-to-display-questions-with-tag-x-that-are-unanswered/57638#57638) is the most effective, the new advanced search does have a method if your desires are purely questions with 0 answers (rather than no upvoted or accepted answers). Just enter the following into your search bar to, for example, get all C++ questions without answers:

> answers:0 [c++]