# Profile: add an open questions filter option?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

The StackOverflow question list looks like this (on my profile):

[image]

I would like to filter out the "open" questions. Is this possible? Can this feature be created?

Comment: If you do a question search using [`user:201482 hasaccepted:0`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A201482+hasaccepted%3A0) you will find all your questions for which you have not yet accepted an answer.

Comment: This is on your profile rather than on the home page? Can you make that clear in your question.

Comment: @ChrisF, it is on my profile

Comment: @Bart, pretty cool, but not very user friendly ;-)

Comment: I find it easy to use. If you need a quick reference, type `@` into the search bar. It gives you [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%40).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is actually already available via search functionality.:

`hasaccepted:0 user:me`

[Try it out now!](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A0+user%3Ame)

And check

1. [View my questions with unaccepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/view-my-questions-with-unaccepted-answers)
2. [Unable to find unaccepted answers effectively](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1088/178505)

And this feature request is made so many times and it is always voted high. Though this feature requests had no any response. No [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) or [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) or [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) :

1. [Sort questions in user profile by "Unaccepted" or "Date accepted"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60557/sort-questions-in-user-profile-by-unaccepted-or-date-accepted)
2. [I'd like to be able to see all of my unanswered questions in my questions profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71564/id-like-to-be-able-to-see-all-of-my-unanswered-questions-in-my-questions-profil?lq=1)
3. ["Unanswered" question sort order on profile pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36103/unanswered-question-sort-order-on-profile-pages?lq=1)

Comment: If it's requested so many times, then why isn't it build in yet..

Comment: @ErikDekker: I am not official for saying why isn't it built. I think may be because we are still able to find unaccepted questions through 'hasaccepted:0 user:me'. And their might be serious high priority issues being solved than this feature request.