# How to find questions I asked?

Tags: discussion

I can't find questions I asked in Stack Overflow, and some questions are unaccepted but I can't find them. Where can I find my unaccepted questions and asked questions?
[image]

Comment: Guys most likely he means questions that got deleted so he can't see them anymore in the profile..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to find unaccepted answers effectively](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1081/unable-to-find-unaccepted-answers-effectively)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question does not appear in the *Questions* tab in your profile, it means it got deleted. Only a moderator can still see it in your profile and only moderators or users with more than 10,000 reputation can view such question.

You can ask a moderator (here in Meta or by flagging one of your own existing posts) to have a look telling what to look for and he can explain why it got deleted.

As for "questions are unaccepted" I assume you mean questions you still did not choose accepted answer? In such case, it's possible to distinguish them in the [Questions tab in your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084732/vienna?tab=questions) by the text color - only if the color of the text is yellow it means you accepted an answer otherwise you didn't:

[image]

When you have many questions or want only the questions without accepted answer in one list you can use advanced search for this, just add "hasaccepted:0" to the search query. Here is the full search link: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1084732+hasaccepted%3A0

Comment: I think he means "How do I find my questions where I've not accepted an answer?"

Comment: @George good catch! Will update my post shortly.

Comment: thank you, I can find the question I asked, I just need to know how to find the questions I haven't accepted.

Answer (score 3):

The 'questions' menu item, between 'answers' and 'tags.'

Answer (score 3):

If you are signed-in, you should be able to browse to the questions section using this URL https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions

*our witty server will automagically resolve the value or `current` (user)*  (-: