# I'd like to see all my questions waiting for me to accept an answer, across the network, in one overview

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, accepted-answer, network-profile

I'd like to see all my questions waiting for me to accept an answer, across the network, in one overview, possibly on my network profile page.

#### Rationale

I have a couple of "core" stacks I visit frequently. Most other stacks are "drive by" stacks, where I've asked the occasional question.

I *know* [how to search for questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276187/239016) I've asked where I *could have* but *have not* accepted an answer — per site.
I've also seen [the solution using the SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259795/239016).

But what I'd like to see is one single overview of questions that are still waiting for me to accept an answer. This would preferably find its home on my user profile or my network profile.